# SONAR importing cobertura.ser coverage reports to sonar server using mvn sonar:sonar?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, cobertura

I have a cobertura.ser file, that got generated while integration-test and system test. Now I want to import my coverage this to sonar server.

How can I achieve this, so while executing mvn sonar:sonar the coverage should consider external coberture.ser file?

Can I do this using sonar, where i can see overall coverage obtain during all test run?

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the following paramater to tell Sonar to use a pre-generated report:

```
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
```

Secondly Sonar doesn't read the "cobertura.ser" file. It can be configured as follows to read the generated XML report (See cobertura docs):

```
sonar.cobertura.reportPath=target/reports/coverage.xml
```

Finally, my reference for all this stuff comes from the from the Sonar wiki:

- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Advanced+Parameters
- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests
- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Integration+Tests

The Sonarsource tutorials are increasingly pushing JaCoCo. This appears to be an emerging standard (replacing the older defunct Emma project)