# Sonar + Multi Module Maven Projects

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, cobertura

I am calling Sonar from my Jenkins job
I noticed that the coverage of the classes in my domain module all show as having 0% test coverage even though the domains are being used in the other modules which have high test coverage. I am using cobertura within Sonar for measuring the coverage

Can anyone offer any insights into how to get Sonar/Cobertura to recognise the test coverage for the classes in the domain module

Thanks
Damien

Comment: Did you set the appropriate Sonar properties for reusing your code coverage reports as described in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049123/sonar-importing-cobertura-ser-coverage-reports-to-sonar-server-using-mvn-sonars)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Sonar computes unit test coverage. So if your domain classes are not unit-tested in the module where they are defined, this is normal that you don't get unit test coverage for those.

You can have a look at how to add integration test coverage in Sonar: see https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/combined%20ut-it/combined-ut-it-multimodule-maven-jacoco

But that'd be best to have "real" unit tests for your domain classes to test their logic in an isolated context.

**Edit**
[Link to sonar-exmaple-multiple-modules](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/projects/multi-module/sonar-runner/java-sonar-runner-modules-different-structures/sonar-project.properties)

Comment: thanks Fabrice, that makes sense.. I will look at the link you provided and integrate it with our code base. thanks for your help